# How to make SymPy Max(2,n) be n?

Tags: python, max, sympy

I'm practicing SymPy and find out `Max` operator can not solve when value is greater than `1`.

```py
n = Symbol('n', integer=True, positive=True)
Max(1,n)    # this works fine
Max(2,n)    # output Max(2, n)
```

I'm confusing why `Max` can not solve it when the other value is greater than `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try rewrite as Piecewise to see the conditions of Max explicitly:

```
>>> Max(2,n).rewrite(Piecewise)
Piecewise((2, n <= 2), (n, True))
```

Comment: hello, can i specify `n` is always greater than `2`??

Comment: set n = 2 + symbols('eps', positive=True)

Answer (score 1):

Both results are correct.  If `n` must be a positive integer, then the answer to `Max(1, n)` will be `n` for any `n`.  But for `Max(2, n)`, the answer will be `n` if `n > 1`, otherwise it will be `2`. A way to state that is `Max(2, n)`, and that's what SymPy is telling you.

Take off the `positive` constraint on `n` and then both answers will come out in the same form as the input, because now `Max(1, n)` will no longer be `n` for all possible values of `n` that meet the restrictions (all integers).

Comment: and may i ask another question why `O(Max(2, n), (n,oo))` won't be `O(n)` even i had given `n` approaches infinity??

Comment: I don't have an answer for this one.

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer again, I'll try to figure out why `O` can not solve `Max()`.